# how to scroll a div to specific ofset point by jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to scroll div2 to 200px top of offset. how to add 200px to below script. please help

```
$(document).ready(function (){
            $("#click").click(function (){
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#div2").offset().top
                }, 2000); 

            });
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9yGCf/14/

Comment: div2 will be after content area like footer(height 600 + px) that need to scroll to top (to offset 200px.  )

Comment: got it ! scrollTop: $("#div2").offset().top - 200